# How to override `storefront/component/line-item/element/label.html.twig` on cart page?

Tags: twig, shopware6

Would like to override `storefront/component/line-item/element/label.html.twig` file available on the cart page.

I tried to add the below code in the override twig template then it is throwing an error as

```
"Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden"
```

```
{% block component_line_item_label %}
    {{ parent() }}
        some custom text 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: "*n the override twig template*" - What do you mean by this? You've created a new template? If so, you would still need to either `extend` or `embed` the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to extend the original template file, see [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/customize-templates#custom-template-content%20and%20https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/storefront-reference/twig-function-reference#functions) for more information

So your template should look like this:

```
{% sw_extends @Storefront/storefront/component/line-item/element/label.html.twig %}

{% block component_line_item_label %}
    {{ parent() }}
        some custom text 
{% endblock %}
```